# Starcraft 2 maps?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am new and need to study the maps. Is there a good place to download them? All 1v1 maps. Just need decent enough resolution to print them out.

Comment: This is off-topic, as per our FAQ. Specifically, "Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game) and Shopping advice and recommendations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [teamliquid.net wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Maps#1v1) has images of all the maps. The images have quite high resolution, so that all important details should be visible.

If you want to create your own pictures, you can also open the maps in the map editor and then export them as an image using *Data* -> *Export Map Image*.

You can open maps directly from battle.net and you can choose what details you want included in the exported image, so you can create your own custom images without too much trouble.

Comment: No need to have two answers here. Perhaps you should merge them?

Comment: Those are really high resolution, very nice!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of them here.  Not the best resolution, but better than nothing.

http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Category:StarCraft_II_map_images